# Add data to array inside struct

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2010, struct

**How can I set data into the array of 3 rows which at the same time has an array of 4 elements?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"

typedef struct
{
    char value[6];
} MyType;

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    MyType *values;
} NewType;

static NewType car;
static MyType mytype = {{'\0'}};

void Init(NewType *car)
{
    car->size = 3; // Will contain 3 rows of 4 elements
    car->values = (MyType*) calloc(car->size,sizeof(MyType));
}

// Get data into
void Write(NewType *car, MyType *data)
{
   strcpy(car->values[0].value, data[0].value); // ** Here is where complains

   printf("%d\n", car->values[0]); // Printing wrong data!
}

int main()
{
    Init(&car);

    strcpy(mytype.value, "Hello"); 

    Write(&car, &mytype);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the `printf` to show? If you change it to `printf("%s\n", car->values[0].value);`, then it will print `Hello`.

Comment: "Hello" needs array of 6 not 4.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code `strcpy(mytype.value, "Hello");` you are copying a 5 letters string into an  array of 4 chars, which is illegal, so that might be causing the error. Either change the string you copy to `mytype.value` for a shorter one (like `"Bye"`) or increase the number of elements in the `value` char array to the number of characters of the word you want to put in there plus one for the terminating null character.

Additionally the `printf()` statement in the `Write()` function has a format string that indicates to print an `int`, which I doubt is what you actually want. The following are the rewritten `Write()` and `main()` functions.

```
void Write(NewType *car, MyType *data)
{
   strcpy(car->values[0].value, data->value);

   printf("%s\n", car->values[0].value); 
}

int main()
{
    Init(&car);

    strcpy(mytype.value, "Bye"); 

    Write(&car, &mytype);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: @valter You are correct in that `values` is a pointer so the `->` would also work, but the `values` pointer is conceived as a collection of values and both expressions are equivalent (`values->value = values[0].value`, `(values + 1)->value = values[1].value`, and so on) so it's just a matter of preference in this case.

Comment: Yes of course! (*values).value is the same as values->value. silly me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `printf("%d\n", car->values[0])` you are actually trying to print the first 4 bytes of the memory you have calloced inside your `Init()`, formatted as a signed decimal integer. (4 in case of x86. `sizeof(int)` in general).

To print the value, you should:

```
printf("%s\n", car->values->value);
```